# Click Item In ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

ok, now i have done all i can and i am screwed. how do i make it so that i can click every item in my list and edit the text inside of it? right now i have hardcoded 2 items in the list, and when i click on on of them i want to be able to edit and add content to it.
i have no freaking idea what to do.
please help me!

my notelist class

```
package se.felix.anteckningsblock;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Notelist extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




            setContentView(R.layout.notelist);

            notes.add("Handlingslista");
            notes.add("Kom Ihåg");

            ArrayAdapter<String> list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);
            setListAdapter(list);
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // <---- use this to notify data change to update list!!!111oneoneoneleven


            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.New);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Notelist.this, anteckningsblock.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

    }
}
```

my anteckningsblock class (this is where i edit my notes, and create new ones, but it doesn't work yet)

```
package se.felix.anteckningsblock;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;


public class anteckningsblock extends ActionBarActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anteckningsblock);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.GoBack);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(anteckningsblock.this, Notelist.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    }

}
```

if you need anything else please tell me and i will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using edittext instead of textviews to fill your listView up

Answer (score 0):

Put this array in a singleton class or make it static -(consider taking the first option)

```
ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();
```

now in your **listActivity class** catch the item that has been clicked/or the index with `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` method. then pass it using the intent for startactivity `intent.putString()` and pass your string

```
Intent i = new Intent(anteckningsblock.this, Notelist.class);
i.putString("myarraypos",position); // the key is the name you use to retrieve..
startActivity(i); // i am passing the int of the array so we can edit it
```

note that the above code should be in the onListItemClick function above

and edit and replace it with the old one, in your static arraylist

```
//assuming you are done editing
Classname.notes.add(getintent().getStringExtra("myarraypos"),value);
```

correct code names and code

Comment: i don't have a listActivity class, do i need to make a new class?

Comment: no Sir, i mean **Notelist.class**, but since it extended ListActivity i just called it listactivity class.. @EatenMoth72

Answer (score 0):

i solved it. thanks @Elitz for getting me on the right track :)

i just put this inside my **Notelist Class**

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Notelist.this, anteckningsblock.class);
        startActivity(i);
```